# A basic question on the complete flag variety

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, geometry, linear-groups

I was reading [in this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety) about Generalized flag variety, but didn't understand the actions of $GL_n$ and $SU_n$ on the set of all complete flags.

> Specially, how to prove that $SL(n,\mathbb C)/B\cong SU(n)/T$, where $B$ is the subgroup of  upper triangular matrices and $T$ is the subgroup of the diagonal $n×n$-matrices?
>
> Furthermore, when $n=3$, what is $SU(3)/T$ explicitly?

Comment: What's the equivalence? Diffeomorphism?

Comment: Yes diffeomorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flag in $\bf C^n$ is a family of vector spaces $E_0={0}\subset E_1\subset..\subset E_n= \bf C^n$. Both of the member of the identity identify with the set of flags : given a flag one can choose a base (resp. an orthornormal) base $B=(e_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ such that $E_i= Vect(e_1,...,e_i)$. Conversely such a base $B$ defines a flag, and two bases $B,B'$ give the same flag if and only the matrix of changing the base from $B$ to $B'$ is an upper triangular matrix $T$ (resp. a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of absolute value 1). One can identify the set of bases (orthonormal bases) with $Sl(n,\bf C)$ and $U(n)$ to get the result.

Comment: thanks Thomas! I've another question now: If $n=3$, can we find $SU(3)/T$ explicitly? thanks again :)

Comment: I edited the question so you can also edit your answer with the new addition.. :)

Comment: You can can describe a complete flag in $\bf C^3$ as a pair $(L,P)$ where $L$ is a line and $P$ a plane containing $L$. Choose a unit vector $e$ in $L$, $f\in P\cup L^\perp$, and a vector $g \in P^\perp $ to get a orthonormal basis, or a matrix in $U(3)$. This choice is unique modulo $U(1)^3$. Hence the set of flags is $U(3)/U(1)^3$.

Comment: Is that equal to $\{(u,v)\in P^2(\mathbb{C})\times P^2(\mathbb{C})|u\perp v\}$? If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: $P^n(\mathbb C)$ can be thought of as the space of lines in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$ or the space hyperplanes (subspaces of codimension 1) in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$...